# How to use string array in for loop

Tags: groovy

I have the below string declaration and i am using the string in for loop:

```
String[] values = new String["A","B","C"]
for (int i = 0, length = values.length; i < length; i++)
    {
        getData(values[i], i, length);
    }
```

Throwing an error "unexpected token: = @" at for loop line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groovy is different for creating string arrays, you'd do

```
String[] values = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

You could also do what you're trying to do with

```
def values = ​["A","B","C"]
values.eachWithIndex { item, idx -> 
    getData(item, idx, values.size())
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: i tried the String[] values = ['A', 'B', 'C']  declaration but it still throws the same error in the for loop,

Comment: Yeah, for loops in groovy don't accept multiple variables as in Java

Comment: The `eachWithIndex` above should do the same as you're trying with the for loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write valid Java, you have to initialize your array with the values wanted in curly braces and that looks like:

```
String[] values = new String[]{"A","B","C"};
for (int i = 0, length = values.length; i < length; i++) {
    getData(values[i], i, length);
}
```

If you want to do that in Groovy, just use:

```
String[] values  = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]
values.eachWithIndex { v, i ->
  getData(v, i, values.size())
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just saw the `java` tag which was still there at the beginning, I've updated my answer and also put the Groovy solution.

Comment: Sorry, just saw the `java` which was once there on your question. I'll updated my answer now also with the Groovy part.

Answer (score -1):

In your code example you did not use a semicolon after the initialization of the for loop.
for example,

for(var i= 0; i

compiling without the semicolon will give you an error, not initializing the I variable.